# Python lxml & starting out with xpath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Reasonably new to Python and incredibly new to XML much less trying to parse it.  I need to identify cluster nodes from a series of weblogic XML configuration files.  I've figured out how to get 75% of them; now, I'm going after the edge case and I'm unsure how to proceed.

Weblogic XML config files start with namespace definitions then a number of child elements some of which have children of their own.

The element that I'm interested in is `<server>` which will usually have a subelement called `<listen-address>` containing the hostname that I'm looking for.

Following the paradigm of "we love standards, we got lots of them", this model doesn't work everywhere.  Where it doesn't work, I need to look for a subelement of `<server>` called `<machine>`.  That element contains an alias which is expanded in a different root child, at the same level as `<server>`.

So, picture worth a 1000 words:

Note: was trying to avoid sending tons of xml; but, apparently, my attempts at bandwidth saving makes the problem harder to answer.  Apologies.  I did trim down un-needed or security related child elements.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd">
  <name>EDIServices_Domain</name>
  <domain-version>12.2.1.0.0</domain-version>
  <security-configuration>
    <name>EDIServices_Domain</name>
    <default-realm>myrealm</default-realm>
    <node-manager-username>snipped</node-manager-username>
    <node-manager-password-encrypted>not_really_my_pwd</node-manager-password-encrypted>
  </security-configuration>
  <server>
    <name>EDIServices_AS</name>
    <listen-port>60010</listen-port>
    <web-server>
      <name>EDIServices_AS</name>
      <web-server-log>
        <file-name>/opt/app/oracle/user_projects/logs/EDIServices_Domain/access.log</file-name>
        <file-count>24</file-count>
        <file-min-size>10000</file-min-size>
        <rotate-log-on-startup>true</rotate-log-on-startup>
        <elf-fields>c-ip cs-uri date time cs-method cs-uri sc-status</elf-fields>
        <log-file-format>common</log-file-format>
      </web-server-log>
    </web-server>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
  </server>
  <server>
    <name>EDIServices_MS1</name>
    <machine>EDIServices_MC1</machine>
    <listen-port>60014</listen-port>
    <cluster>EDIServices_CS</cluster>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
  </server>
  <server>
    <name>EDIServices_MS2</name>
    <machine>EDIServices_MC2</machine>
    <listen-port>60014</listen-port>
    <cluster>EDIServices_CS</cluster>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
  </server>
  <cluster>
    <name>EDIServices_CS</name>
    <cluster-messaging-mode>unicast</cluster-messaging-mode>
    <dynamic-servers>
      <maximum-dynamic-server-count>0</maximum-dynamic-server-count>
    </dynamic-servers>
  </cluster>
  <production-mode-enabled>true</production-mode-enabled>
  <configuration-version>12.2.1.0.0</configuration-version>
<machine xsi:type="unix-machineType">
    <name>EDIServices_MC1</name>
    <node-manager>
      <name>EDIServices_MC1</name>
      <nm-type>SSL</nm-type>
      <listen-address>host001</listen-address>
      <listen-port>7001</listen-port>
    </node-manager>
  </machine>
  <machine xsi:type="unix-machineType">
    <name>EDIServices_MC2</name>
    <node-manager>
      <name>EDIServices_MC2</name>
      <listen-address>host002</listen-address>
      <listen-port>7001</listen-port>
    </node-manager>
  </machine>
</domain>
```

So, running it on 'normal' config, I get:

```
$ ./lxml configs/EntsvcSoa_Domain_config.xml  
EntsvcSoa_AS    => host003.myco.com
EntsvcSoa_MS1   => host004.myco.com
EntsvcSoa_MS2   => host005.myco.com
```

Running it against the abi-normal config, I'm currently getting:

```
$ ./lxml configs/EDIServices_Domain_config.xml
EDIServices_MS1 => EDIServices_MC1
EDIServices_MS2 => EDIServices_MC2
```

Using the examples above, I would like to translate EDIServices_MC1 and EDIServices_MC2 to host001 and host002 respectively.

The primary loop is:

NOTE: in the interest of being complete, here's the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from lxml import etree
import re
import sys
import os
import pprint

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
  print('Format: ./wl_clusters ${weblogic_config_file}')
  sys.exit(1)

if not os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
  print('Format: ./wl_clusters ${weblogic_config_file}')
  sys.exit(2)

config = sys.argv[1]

# set up lxml structures
tree = etree.parse(config)
root = tree.getroot()

# set up xml namespace govno
ns = root.nsmap[None]
namespaces = { 'ns': ns }

for server in root.findall('ns:server', namespaces):
  cs = server.find('ns:cluster', namespaces)
  if cs is None:
    continue
  # cluster_name = server.find('ns:cluster', namespaces).text
  cluster_name = cs.text
  listen_address = server.find('ns:listen-address', namespaces)
  server_name = listen_address.text
  if server_name is None:
    machine = server.find('ns:machine', namespaces)
    if machine is None:
      continue
    else:
      server_name = machine.text

  print("%-15s => %s" % (cluster_name, server_name))
```

(it's taken me *days* to write 12 lines of code... good thing I don't do this for a living :) )

Rephrased, I need to find the  under the `<machine>` child who's name matches the name under the corresponding `<server>` child.  From some of the examples on the web, I believe xpath might help but I've not been able to get even the simple examples working.

Comment: Add a usable snippet of the xml

Comment: <domain></domain> element is one per xml file or there is many of them?

Comment: Provide a valid XML sample document, especially including any namespace declarations. This is important.

Comment: Hey;  apologies: was trying to avoid the wall of text that I'm regularly accused of writing.   Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of using xpath with your file. I process every element "domain" and show "names of *", which works since they are on same level within .

```
from lxml import etree
xp = etree.XPath('./*/name')
for event, elem in etree.iterparse("delme.xml", events=('end',), tag="domain"):
    for name in xp(elem):
        print(name.text)
```

Output:

```
EDIServices_MS1
EDIServices_MS2
EDIServices_MC1
EDIServices_MC2
```

Edit: created a crude xpath to match both patterns.